# Projection is not found when importing PostgreSQL file with Geopandas

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geopandas, proj, pyproj

I need to import a couple of files from my PostgreSQL database, which has columns with the geometrical data stored in the CRS "epsg:1330". There are no problems with opening the files using Pandas or QGIS (the database has the "postgis" extension). I am on a Windows computer and using the following code:

```
query = 'select * from "Schema"."table"'
wells = gpd.read_postgis(sql = text(query),con=engine.connect())
```

But it returns with this error message:

```
  File "pyproj\_crs.pyx", line 2352, in pyproj._crs._CRS.__init__
pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:1330: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)
```

I am interested in importing the database table with geometry, same as if I was importing a shapefile directly, similar of doing:

```
df=gpd.read_file("file.sh")
```

I can open the files from the database as long as I don't use the geometry:

```
query = 'select * from "Schema"."table"'
wells=pd.read_sql_query(sql = text(query),con=engine.connect())
```

I am using a conda environment installed from an yml where all packages are installed with conda-forge or as defaults. These are the packages:

```
 - python=3.9
  - pip
  - pandas 
  - geopandas 
  - numpy 
  - matplotlib 
  - jupyter 
  - notebook 
  - scipy 
  - openpyxl 
  - xlrd
  - rasterio>=1.0
  - rasterstats
  - pyyaml
  - shapely
  - xarray
  - netcdf4
  - rtree
  - pyproj>=2.0
  - pyshp
  - gdal
  - fiona
  - psutil
```

Why is it not working? I have looked at [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66425565/crserror-invalid-projection-epsg4326-for-geopandas) but it did not solve my problem, as I did not install packages with pip. But I am also a bit new so it might be that I am missing some technical detail.

Comment: Hi, I can't find EPSG:1330 either. Can you please include the output of a new query: `'SELECT s.*, "POINT(0 0)"::geometry as geom FROM "Schema".geometry_columns AS g JOIN "Schema".spatial_ref_sys AS s USING (srid) WHERE g.f_table_name = "table"'`?

Comment: [EPSG:1330](https://epsg.io/1330) seems to be a transformation not a projection, so it seems unlikely that your data is in that, I would go back to the metadata or supplier to find out what the actual projection is

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. I tried to run the suggested SQL and looked more into the transformation. You are right, the problem was with the transformation of the geometrical data and not with Geopandas/pyproj. So I have changed the CRS and now it works.